# Simulating multivariate normals with different covariance matrices

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to simulate draws from multivariate normals with different covariance matrices (after Gibbs sampling). I have used `rmvnorm` (in the library `mvtnorm`) inside a loop, but that is very slow. I have also tried to use an `array` and pass it to `rmvnorm`, but didn't suceed, either. I've used `apply`, and also tried `sapply` on a list, but it isn't significantly faster.

Is there a fast way to do this? 
Thanks!

**EDIT:** My code looks something like this (with more dimensions and simulations). I'm using `mvtnorm::rmvnorm`.

```
library(mvtnorm)
covs = array(dim=c(5,5,2))
covs[,,1] = diag(5)
covs[,,2] = 5*diag(5)
sample = matrix(nrow=2, ncol=5)
for (i in 1:2) {
    sample[i,] = rmvnorm(1, sigma=covs[,,i])
}
apply(covs, 3, function(x) rmvnorm(1, sigma=x)) # tried apply
l1 = list() # also tried with a list
l1[[1]] = diag(5)
l1[[2]] = 5*diag(5)
sapply(l1, function(x) rmvnorm(1, sigma=x))
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: you said `mvrnorm` in the text but you have `rmvnorm` in the code (there is an `rmvnorm` in the `mvtnorm` package ...).  Most of the speed penalty of `mvrnorm` probably comes from the need to decompose the covariance matrix (e.g. by taking eigenvalues). You might experiment with the speed of using different `method` arguments in `mvtnorm::rmvnorm` ...

Comment: could you confirm that you are using `rmvnorm` from the `mvtnorm` package?  (`library("sos"); findFn("rmvnorm")` shows that there are `rmvnorm()` functions in at least a half-dozen packages)

Comment: Maybe there should be a checklist for posting R questions that requires the poster to specify any packages used besides 'base', 'stats', and 'graphics'?

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, I'm using `mvtnorm::rmvnorm`.

Comment: general thoughts (I may not get back to this, I should be doing other things): (1) I would experiment with using other values of `method`; (2) the `rbenchmark` package is useful; (3) ultimately you may not be able to speed things up much unless you rearrange your Gibbs sampler to sample on the scale of the Cholesky factor (so no need to decompose at every step) rather than on the scale of the covariance matrix ...